# Why would running a container on GCE get stuck Metadata request unsuccessful forbidden (403)

Tags: metadata, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to run a container in a custom VM on Google Compute Engine. This is to perform a heavy ETL process so I need a large machine but only for a couple of hours a month. I have two versions of my container with small startup changes. Both versions were built and pushed to the same google container registry by the same computer using the same Google login. The older one works fine but the newer one fails by getting stuck in an endless list of the following error:

E0927 09:10:13 7f5be3fff700 api_server.cc:184 Metadata request unsuccessful: Server responded with 'Forbidden' (403): Transport endpoint is not connected

Can anyone tell me exactly what's going on here? Can anyone please explain why one of my images doesn't have this problem (well it gives a few of these messages but gets past them) and the other does have this problem (thousands of this message and taking over 24 hours before I killed it).

If I ssh in to a GCE instance then both versions of the container pull and run just fine. I'm suspecting the INTEGRITY_RULE checking from the logs but I know nothing about how that works.

MORE INFO: this is down to "restart policy: never". Even a simple Centos:7 container that says "hello world" deployed from the console triggers this if the restart policy is never. At least in the short term I can fix this in the entrypoint script as the instance will be destroyed when the monitor realises that the process has finished

Comment: I don't have a strong sense of what's going wrong but... Have you tried creating a 3rd container that's focused on the metadata service functionality to isolate the issue? When you say "small startup changes" perhaps they're small but significant; are you willing to reference your scripts in this question? Can you `curl` the metadata service from the VM? Is it the same VM? Is the request to the metadata service using the VM's service account? It feels perhaps there's a timing difference between the 2 containers that's not being overcome.

Comment: I have no metadata fuinctionality. These errors are happening before the docker entrypoint is being called. This container is from on-prem and knows nothing about GCP

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try creating a 3rd container that's focused on the metadata service functionality to isolate the issue. It may be that there's a timing difference between the 2 containers that's not being overcome.

Make sure you can ‘curl’ the metadata service from the VM and that the request to the metadata service is using the VM's service account.

Comment: I have no metadata fuinctionality. These errors are happening before the docker entrypoint is being called. This container is from on-prem and knows nothing about GCP